# How to deal with a c++ program taking runtime input in bash file?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, scripting

In detail, I have a c++ program which takes runtime input of different parameters. I am creating a shell script to automate my process. But the program needs input to be given in the terminal. How do I send the input value from bash when the terminal prompts to enter the input value?

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the input from standard input (through `std::cin`), or to pass it as arguments to the program?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use usual flow (pipelining or redirecting) to feed your program with data

```sh
./a.out < myFileWithdata.txt
#or with pipelining
echo "my one line" | ./a.out
```

Another option is to use "here-document":

```sh
./a.out << EOF
My first line!
My second line.
EOF
#more commands
```

*Note:* EOF is just a convention, it can be any string that will mark end of data to pass to program.

Another option, to pass one line quickly is "here-string":

```sh
./a.out <<< "My data!"
#more commands
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was helpful.

Comment: Good luck in your programming! :)